# Should a component adapter wrap just the component or should it also wrap <Field>

Tags: react-final-form

### Best concept for wrapping react-final-form components

#### Background

I'm using react-native and will probably start using react-final-form as soon as I have wrapped my head around it. I will build a component library based on react-native-paper.

All examples I've seen on wrapping 3:rd party components for use as react-final-form fields (i.e. `<Field>`), does not wrap the actual field component. Instead the wrapped component is injected via the `component` property of the `Field` component.

If I'm doing all the work wrapping the components, why not go all the way? Since I haven't found any examples of the "complete wrapping", I'm kind of worried that it's not a good idea.

Both solutions seems to work fine, btw. The code below is psuedo:ish.

#### Only wrapping the component

```
export default function App() {
  const CheckboxAdapter = ({input: {onChange, value}, meta}) => (
    <Checkbox
      status={value}
      onPress={() => {
        onChange(value === 'checked' ? 'unchecked' : 'checked');
      }}
      errorText={meta.touched ? meta.error : ''}
    />
  );

  return (
    <Form
      ..
      render={({handleSubmit}) => {
        return (
          ..
           <Field
             name="myFieldname"
             component={CheckboxAdapter}
           />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

#### Wrapping the component inside of the `<Field>` component

```
export default function App() {
  const MyCheckbox = ({name}) => (
    <Field
      name={name}
      component={({input: {onChange, value}, meta, children, ...rest}) => (
        <Checkbox
          status={value}
          onPress={() => {
            onChange(value === 'checked' ? 'unchecked' : 'checked');
          }}
          errorText={meta.touched ? meta.error : ''}
        />
      )};
    />
  );

  return (
    <Form
      ..
      render={({handleSubmit}) => {
        return (
          ..
           <MyCheckbox
             name="myFieldname"
           />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: While looking at my own code above, I see that the second solution will suffer from "inline-function-definition-syndrome". This is easily solved by defining the inlined function separately, but still wrap it inside of a Field via the component property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much interest in this question. I ended up wrapping the `<Field>`as well. This gives much more readable form code.

```
import React from 'react';
import TextInput from '../components/TextInput';
import {Field} from 'react-final-form';

const TextInputAdapter = ({input, meta, ...rest}) => {
  const onChangeText = value => {
    input.onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <TextInput
      {...input}
      {...rest}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      errorText={meta.touched ? meta.error : ''}
    />
  );
};

const TextInputField = ({...rest}) => {
  return <Field component={TextInputAdapter} {...rest} />;
};

export default TextInputField;
```

Comment: The answer is that you can do it both ways. There is no right or wrong option here.

So your way is just fine. 